# Soap Request using axis2 java in Eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, servicenow

I want to make an insert operation in an import set table through the web service from ServiceNow with axis2 version 1.6.4

I used wsdl2java with the wsdl file to create classes in my java project.

After it, i created a new class Request on which i would build my soap request to the webservice.

I believe I have 2 (might be more) major problems:

- Unserstanding the difference between a stub and a proxy, respectively, the classes ServiceNowSoapStub and ServiceNowSoapProxy and what is the purpose of each of them.
- The existing insert method needs a lot of arguments and i wish to make inserts with a selected number of arguments. do i need to add that specific insert method to the architecture?

Here is what I have:

```
public class Request {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        try{
            HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuthentication = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
            basicAuthentication.setUsername("xxxx");
            basicAuthentication.setPassword("xxxx");

            ServiceNowSoapStub proxy = new ServiceNowSoapStub();
            proxy._setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
            proxy._setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuthentication);

            BigDecimal actuals = new BigDecimal("0.04");
            BigInteger appId = new BigInteger("3495766");
            String appNonApp = "ApNon";
            BigInteger productId = new BigInteger("704217");
            BigInteger serviceId = new BigInteger("1537");
            String serviceName = "IT";
            String bpName = "BNK-RSK";
            String method = "N";
            String bsCode = "ITDV";
            String customerCostCode = "30973250";
            String customerCountry = "US";
            String customerGroup = "Wealth";
            String customerLegalEntity = "HB";
            String dsId = "EU56";
            BigInteger supplierCostCode = new BigInteger("675136");
            String supplierCountry = "UK";
            String supplierLegalEntity = "BR";  
            BigInteger total = new BigInteger ("411");

            ServiceNowSoapProxy request = new ServiceNowSoapProxy("https://dev34363.service-now.com/u_it_actuals_import_set");

            request.insertTest(actuals, appId, appNonApp, productId, serviceId, serviceName, bpName, method, bsCode, customerCostCode, 
                    customerCountry, customerGroup, customerLegalEntity, dsId, supplierCostCode, supplierCountry, supplierLegalEntity, total);          

        } catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? or can please anyone refer me to some helpful link?

The wiki page of servicenow addressing this subject is a bit out of date so i can't solve my problem through it.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Number of parameters passed in (18) doesn't match the number of IN/INOUT parameters (20) from the addParameter() calls